# ASP.NET [Refresh my page :) ]

Tags: asp.net, refresh

How need I to refresh my page after SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
for my GridView appears this new data.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the page to periodically refresh, to reflect updated items in a database?

Comment: That's looking like my function

DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged

doesn't calls ... 
I've no idea why.

Comment: I no need to refresh (tested with button)
I need function

for drop down list that calls after I change the node :)

Comment: and why
DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged doesn't works

Comment: It might be that you have not put AutoPostBack="true" on the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grid view has a [DataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx) event to which you can subscribe to and achieve the desired behaviour by calling `Response.Redirect(Request.RawURL)` or via javascript `window.location.reload()`

Comment: Update that to Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

Comment: since you seem to be living in victorian with the way your question is written...
:P
No ... that's my Russian accent >___<

Comment: By the way ... nothing happens.

Making 

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters[2].DefaultValue = "1";

            SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

T_T

Comment: It might be that you have not put AutoPostBack="true" on the dropdown, cause the response.redirect() will redirect you.

Comment: @Dejan updated to use Request.RawURL @nCdy...apologies then, however, I have noticed your other questions see to be written fine :P

Comment: AutoPostBack="true" 
helps me :) 
Thank you very much ^_^
take a look to my other questions without answers here :P

Comment: @nCdy, my apologies then I actually thought you wrote it deliberatly that way! I have updated.